# GIT URL in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to parameterize a Jenkins pipeline. The only input parameter will be GITHUB_URL. I have a Jenkinsfile as a part of the repo. I want to use this variable (defined as parameter) in my pipeline configuration as "Repository URL". How can I access the parameter ?

I have tried $GITHUB_URL, ${GITHUB_URL} and ${params.GITHUB_URL}. No luck

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are telling you have a jenkinsfile inside your git repo I suppose you do not mean that you want to call a Jenkinsfile using parameters from a shared library.

It's also not sure if you are using a declarative or scripted pipeline.
I will explain the "recommended" declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any


    parameters { 
        string(defaultValue: "https://github.com", description: 'Whats the github URL?', name: 'URL')
    }


    stages {
        stage('Checkout Git repository') {
           steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: "${params.URL}"
            }
        }

        stage('echo') {
           steps {
                echo "${params.URL}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this pipeline you will add a string parameter to which you can add a URL. When you run the build it will ask for the parameter:
[image]

To use this parameter use `"${params.URL}"`:
This pipeline will clone the github repo in the first stage and print the URL in the next (echo) stage:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (echo)
[Pipeline] echo
https://github.com/lvthillo/docker-ghost-mysql.git
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer lvthillo.
I am using a scripted pipeline. The Jenkinsfile is a part of the repo https://github.com/vrprasad/sample.git. All I want to do is give this URL as parameter, and Jenkinsfile should be fetched from this.