# dynamically selecting git repo in jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins

In jenkins job, is it possible to have multiple git repositories and dynamically selecting the repository on the basis of parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the git URL in a jenkins pipeline, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568131/git-url-in-jenkins-pipeline):

```
pipeline {
    agent any


    parameters { 
        string(defaultValue: "https://github.com", description: 'Whats the github URL?', name: 'URL')
    }


    stages {
        stage('Checkout Git repository') {
           steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: "${params.URL}"
            }
        }

        stage('echo') {
           steps {
                echo "${params.URL}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is using the [`git` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/#git-git) ([illustrated here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003945572-Pipeline-Build-with-git-step-on-a-specific-branch-is-triggered-by-a-different-branch#resolution))

You can also [set it depending on a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224272/using-a-jenkins-pipeline-to-checkout-multiple-git-repos-into-same-job/51742260), if you needed to checkout *multiple* Git repositories.